# Angular : how to debounce an Observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, debouncing

In my app, I have a service that returns an observable like this :

```
public genericService(params) {
    //Do some stuff
    //...

    return this.http.post('http://foo.com', params)
        .map((response) => {
            //Do some generic stuff
            //...

            return someData;
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
            //Manage error in a generic way + do some generic stuff
            //...

            return Observable.throw(error);
        });
}

let debouncePointer = debounceObservable(genericService, 200);

public genericServiceDebounce(params) {
    return debouncePointer(params);
}
```

Now in another place, I would like to call my function like this

```
genericServiceDebounce(params)
    .subscribe((response) => {
        //Do some non-generic stuff
    }, (error) => {
        //Manage error in a non-generic way + do some non-generic stuff
    });
```

**But I didn't succeed to implement the debounceObservable() function.**

I tried this implementation based on a Promise equivalent ( https://github.com/moszeed/es6-promise-debounce/blob/master/src/es6-promise-debounce.js ) :

```
debounceObservable(callback, delay, immediate?) {
    let timeout;
    return function () {
        let context = this, args = arguments;

        return Observable.create((observer) => {
            let later = function () {
                timeout = null;

                if(!immediate) {
                    observer.next(callback.apply(context, args));
                    //observer.onCompleted(); // don't know if this is needed
                }
            };
            let callNow = immediate && !timeout;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(later, delay);

            if(callNow) {
                observer.next(callback.apply(context, args));
                //observer.onCompleted(); // don't know if this is needed
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But this don't work as expected. 
When using Promises, returning resolve(anotherPromise) allows you to call :

```
genericServiceDebounce().then(response => {

})
```

When using Observables, returning observer.next(anotherObservable) return an embedded observable, which means you should call :

```
genericServiceDebounce().subscribe(obs => {
    obs.subscribe(response => {

    })
})
```

**How would you implement the debounceObservable() function?** (in a Promise like way)

*Clarification 1 : I found the Observable.debounce() function but this debounces the observer and not the observable itself. And I want to debounce the observable*

*Clarification 2 : I placed the debounce on the service side because it is a singleton, and their are multiple callers. If I placed it on caller side, there would be a different debounce timer for each caller.*

EDIT : Here is a snippet where I try to explain my problem. Just click the different buttons to see the different behaviors (more explanation in js code comments).

**Observable.debounce** shows how .debounce() from RxJs works. It outputs only '3' but I want '1', '2', '3'.

**Observable.debounce x3** shows what happens if I call the code 3 times without wrapping my entire function in a debounce.

**Observable wrapped x3** shows what I want to obtain. My entire function is wrapped, but if you look at the code, the subscribe part is fastidious.

**Promise x3** shows how simple it is when using Promises.

```js
let log = (logValue) => {
    const list = document.querySelector('#logs');
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = logValue;
    list.appendChild(li);
}

/* ************************ */
/* WITH OBSERVABLE.DEBOUNCE */
/* ************************ */

let doStuffObservable = () => {
    Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
        log('this should be called only one time (observable.debounce)');
        setTimeout(() => {
            observer.next('observable.debounce 1');
            observer.next('observable.debounce 2');
            observer.next('observable.debounce 3');
        }, 1000);
    })
        .debounce(500)
        .subscribe((response) => {
            log(response);
        }, (error) => {
            log(error);
        });
}

/* *********************************** */
/* WITH OBSERVABLE WRAPPED IN DEBOUNCE */
/* *********************************** */

let doStuffObservable2 = (param) => {
    return Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
        log('this should be called only one time (observable wrapped)');
        setTimeout(() => {
            observer.next('observable wrapped ' + param);
        }, 1000);
    })
}

let debounceObservable = (callback, delay, immediate) => {
    let timeout;
    return function () {
        let context = this, args = arguments;

        return Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
            let later = function () {
                timeout = null;

                if(!immediate) {
                    observer.next(callback.apply(context, args));
                }
            };
            let callNow = immediate && !timeout;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(later, delay);

            if(callNow) {
                observer.next(callback.apply(context, args));
            }
        });
    }
}

let doStuffObservable2Debounced = debounceObservable(doStuffObservable2);

  
/* ************* */
/* WITH PROMISES */
/* ************* */

let doStuffPromise = (param) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        log('this should be called only one time (promise)');
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('promise ' + param);
        }, 1000);
    });
}

let debouncePromise = (callback, delay, immediate) => {
    let timeout;
    return function () {
        let context = this, args = arguments;
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            let later = function () {
                timeout = null;
                
                if (!immediate) {
                    resolve(callback.apply(context, args));
                }
            };
            let callNow = immediate && !timeout;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(later, delay);
            
            if (callNow) {
                resolve(callback.apply(context, args));
            }
        });
    }
}

  
/* ******* */
/* SAMPLES */
/* ******* */

function doObservableDebounce() {
  doStuffObservable();
  
  // result :
  
      // this should be called only one time (observable.debounce)
      // observable.debounce 3
  
  // this is not what i want, i want all three values in output
}

function doObservableDebounce3Times() {
  doStuffObservable();
  doStuffObservable();
  doStuffObservable();
  
  // result :
  
      // this should be called only one time (observable.debounce)
      // this should be called only one time (observable.debounce)
      // this should be called only one time (observable.debounce)
      // observable.debounce 3
      // observable.debounce 3
      // observable.debounce 3
  
  // this is bad
}

function doObservableWrappedDebounce3Times() {
  doStuffObservable2Debounced(1)
      .subscribe((response) => {
          log(response);
          response.subscribe((response2) => {
              log(response2);
          }, (error) => {
              log(error);
          })
      }, (error) => {
          log(error);
      });
  doStuffObservable2Debounced(2)
      .subscribe((response) => {
          log(response);
          response.subscribe((response2) => {
              log(response2);
          }, (error) => {
              log(error);
          })
      }, (error) => {
          log(error);
      });
  doStuffObservable2Debounced(3)
      .subscribe((response) => {
          log(response);
          response.subscribe((response2) => {
              log(response2);
          }, (error) => {
              log(error);
          })
      }, (error) => {
          log(error);
      });
  
  
  // result :
  
      // AnonymousObservable { source: undefined, __subscribe: [Function] }
      // this should be called only one time (observable wrapped)
      // observable wrapped 3
  
  // this is good but there are 2 embedded subscribe
}

function doPromiseDebounce3Times() {
  let doStuffPromiseDebounced = debouncePromise(doStuffPromise);
  
  doStuffPromiseDebounced(1).then(response => {
      log(response);
  })
  doStuffPromiseDebounced(2).then(response => {
      log(response);
  })
  doStuffPromiseDebounced(3).then(response => {
      log(response);
  })
  
  // result :
  
      // this should be called only one time (promise)
      // promise 3
  
  // this is perfect
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="rxjs@4.0.6" data-semver="4.0.6" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.0.6/rx.all.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button onclick='doObservableDebounce()'>Observable.debounce</button>
    <button onclick='doObservableDebounce3Times()'>Observable.debounce x3</button>
    <button onclick='doObservableWrappedDebounce3Times()'>Observable wrapped x3</button>
    <button onclick='doPromiseDebounce3Times()'>Promise x3</button>
    <ul id="logs"></ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel with debounceObservable? RxJS already provides debouncing operators. That's why it is a library and not just observable implementation.

Comment: What does `debounce the observable instead of the observer` mean? `.debounce()` debounces the items going through the stream, observable and observer have nothing to do in there.

Comment: Maybe you mean that you need to use debounceTime?
 http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-debounceTime

Comment: @estus and olivarra1 : As I understand the documentation .debounce() and .debounceTime() both execute the observable's code directly. Then if the Observable emits observer.next() multiple times, the subscribe() callback event will be called only one time. The problem here is that the http.post (in my example) is still executed each time I call the observable code.
What I want is to execute the code inside the observable only one time even if called multiple times in a small limit of time.

Comment: @Ldoppea what do you mean by `.debounce() and .debounceTime() both execute the observable's code directly`? `What I want is to execute the code inside the observable only one time even if called multiple times in a small limit of time` this is what `debounceTime()` does.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko sorry if it is not clear. Here is another try. My code is split in two parts: first one is an asynchronous code (the observable), second one is what I wan't to do after the first one completed (the subscribe). Default .debounce() only debounce the subscribe() part. If I call my function containing the asynchronous code multiple time, I want the asynchronous code to be called only one time. I edited my question with a snippet at the end, it compare the observable.debounce() to the debounce(observable) I try to make.

Comment: the issue here is your definition of "debounce", and a fundamental misunderstanding of observables.  What you're actually looking to do is multicast an observable, you should look into publish and refcount.

Comment: Just to be sure, my definition of "debounce" is "to limit the rate at which a function can fire" (as defined here : https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function ). This is exactly what I want to do. Excepting that I want to limit a function that returns an observable, so I wan't to still be able to subscribe to it. Technically I don't multicast an observable : when called multiple time, the 'debounced' method is called only one time, only the last call will return the desired observable, first calls will return the 'debouncer' observable that will just do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't get any notification from your reply to my comment.

A cleaner Rx-only solution for this problem would be to think of your service call as a stream of events, like so:

```
constructor() {
    this._genericServiceCall$ = new ReplaySubject(1);
    this._genericServiceResult$ = this._genericServiceCall$
        .asObservable()
        .debounceTime(1000)
        .switchMap(params => this._genericService(params));
}

private _genericService(params) {
    //Do some stuff
    //...

    return this.http.post('http://foo.com', params)
        .map((response) => {
            //Do some generic stuff
            //...

            return someData;
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
            //Manage error in a generic way + do some generic stuff
            //...

            return Observable.throw(error);
        });
}

public genericService(params) {
    this._genericServiceCall$.next(params);
    return this._genericServiceResult$; // Optionally add `.take(1)` so the observer has the expected behaviour of only getting 1 answer back
}
```

I see something in this though... which `params` will you accept as the ones that have to get through the private `_genericService`?

Anyway, do you follow what's going on in here? So every time someone calls `genericService()` it won't call the service straight away - instead, it will emit a new `_genericServiceCall$` and return the `_genericServiceResult$` stream. If we take a look on how is this stream defined, we see that's it takes a debounced `_genericServiceCall$` and then maps it to the service call. Theoretically it should work - haven't tried.

Edit: Now I see - You may need to publish the genericServiceResult to make it a hot observable, else it will return as soon as any observer subscribes to it:

```
constructor() {
    this._genericServiceCall$ = new ReplaySubject(1);
    this._genericServiceResult$ = this._genericServiceCall$
        .asObservable()
        .debounceTime(1000)
        .switchMap(params => this._genericService(params))
        .publish();
    const subscription = this._genericServiceResult$.connect();
    // You must store subscription somewhere and dispose it when this object is destroyed - If it's a singleton service this might not be needed.
}
```

Comment: Also consider `throttleTime` instead of debounce: What it does is it emits immediately and doesn't allow any other emision after some time (while debounce every time you get an event, resets a timer that once it's finished it emits)

Comment: Thx, this works like a charm and the take(1) was what I needed too. But i'm not sure why I must store subscription. Seems to work without. Is this related to memory management?

Comment: Also, your implementation works better than mine as all subscriber will receive the next() event after the debounce. With mine only the last subscriber receives it.

Comment: @Ldoppea Yes, it's for memory management - That's why I said that if it's a singleton don't worry about it, but if you are creating this class many times, you must make sure to `.dispose()` this subscription when you want to get rid of it, or else it won't get garbage collected, resulting in a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I found a way. What I should have done is to replace :

```
observer.next(callback.apply(context, args));
```

by

```
callback.apply(context, args).subscribe((response) => {
        observer.next(response)
    }, (error) => {
        observer.error(error);
    });
```

Finally this can be used like a classic observable :

```
debouncedObservable(1)
    .subscribe((response) => {
        log(response);
    }, (error) => {
        log(error);
    });
```

Here is a snippet with the implementation :

```js
let log = (logValue) => {
    const list = document.querySelector('#logs');
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = logValue;
    list.appendChild(li);
}

/* *********************************** */
/* WITH OBSERVABLE WRAPPED IN DEBOUNCE */
/* *********************************** */

let doStuffObservable = (param) => {
    return Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
        log('this should be called only one time (observable wrapped)');
        setTimeout(() => {
            observer.next('observable wrapped ' + param);
        }, 1000);
    })
}

let debounceObservable = (callback, delay, immediate) => {
    let timeout;
    return function () {
        let context = this, args = arguments;

        return Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
            let later = function () {
                timeout = null;

                if(!immediate) {
                    callback.apply(context, args).subscribe((response) => {
                          observer.next(response)
                      }, (error) => {
                          observer.error(error);
                      });
                }
            };
            let callNow = immediate && !timeout;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(later, delay);

            if(callNow) {
                callback.apply(context, args).subscribe((response) => {
                          observer.next(response)
                      }, (error) => {
                          observer.error(error);
                      });
            }
        });
    }
}

let doStuffObservable2Debounced = debounceObservable(doStuffObservable);

/* ******* */
/* SAMPLES */
/* ******* */

function doObservableWrappedDebounce3Times() {
  doStuffObservable2Debounced(1)
      .subscribe((response) => {
          log(response);
      }, (error) => {
          log(error);
      });
      
  doStuffObservable2Debounced(2)
      .subscribe((response) => {
          log(response);
      }, (error) => {
          log(error);
      });
      
  doStuffObservable2Debounced(3)
      .subscribe((response) => {
          log(response);
      }, (error) => {
          log(error);
      });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="rxjs@4.0.6" data-semver="4.0.6" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.0.6/rx.all.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button onclick='doObservableWrappedDebounce3Times()'>Observable wrapped x3</button>
    <ul id="logs"></ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Please comment if you think I missed something.